# Heroku APScheduler runs cron job 5 hours earlier than scheduled

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using apscheduler to have it send a email every weekday at 3pm about stock prices. I have deployed it to heroku, and it worked the first week, but after the weekend, it stopped working and started sending emails at 10am, 5 hours earlier. How do I fix this?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from run import admin_operations, check_list, getData
from urls import stock_urls
 
sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=15)
def scheduled_job():
    admin_operations()
    users = check_list()

    urls = stock_urls.copy()
    getData(urls, users)

sched.start()
```

Comment: You have no control over where in the world your Heroku server is located.  You may need to run your schedule once an hour and check UTC.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Would setting timezone help?

Comment: I suspect that could be done, but you'd have to check the BlockingScheduler documentation to find out.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to check UTC?

Comment: When I change it to 'interval' for every minute, it works. Just cron doesn't work.

Comment: Python `datetime.utcnow` can do that.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

Comment: APScheduler does allow you to set timezone, but do you know if there is a way to have it dynamically set timezones.

Comment: "Dynamically"?  You just need to set it once, right?  The server's timezone isn't going to change.  No, I don't know the API.